# How to run a Shell Script using Server side JS

Tags: javascript, shell

Hi 
I need to call a shell script from a server side java script and in shell script i need to connect to DB2 database and delete some data in few tables.
Can any one help me because I am new to server side script and also shell script

Comment: what server side js container are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Java Script is executed at client side,

Probably you need to make ajax call in order to execute shell script at server.

Use [DWR  Direct Web Remotting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)   .call a Java method from java script and in that method execute shell script like

```
rtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process child = rtime.exec(/bin/bash);
```

Comment: javascript can run Server Side as well. See Node.js

Comment: @Midhat I didn't say java script run at server , I just suggested to make ajax call to server